# how to use panel to display content types but using condition?

Tags: views, navigation, nodes

I have two content types.

Liquor product which have fields [Title, origin, effects, side effects, price, how to drink, etc.. ]
Liquor store fields are [store name, address, contact no.]
I am used panel to display Liquor content.I want to display all content of liqour if they have in store.
For e.g If I am click on absolute vodka then panel display absolute vodka info comes(i.e Title, origin, effects, side effects...) but now i want add condition show all stores which have absolute vodka

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create two blocks in Views, one that shows the Liquor info with a contextual filter of the nid, then a second block that lists stores again with contextual filter and a relationship to the nid of the liquor (with whatever field you are using to relate the store to the liquor).

Once your Views blocks are in place, you can then add them into your panel using the Content tab, then selecting the Content cogwheel on left top corner, then select Add Content, then in the dialog box look under Miscellaneous, you will see your Views blocks listed, add them and you're done!